# Geoserver: Georectification via SLD fails

Tags: geoserver, georeferencing, sld, boundless-suite, wps

### **Situation**

I have a raster image and the coordinates of its four corner pixels. My goal is to warp the image with respect to this coordinates ("georectify") **on the fly** when requested via GeoServer to display in OpenLayers.

Inspired by this [discussion list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.geoserver.user/31477), my idea was to do the following in GeoServer:

1. Create a [WorldImage layer](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/worldimage.html) (raster + text file with geodata)
2. Create a [Styled Layer Descriptor](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-introduction.html) (SLD) calling the [Web Processing Service](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/wps/index.html) (WPS) `GeorectifyCoverage` which "georectifies a raster via Ground Control Points using gdal_warp".
3. Apply the SLD to the layer.

### **Problem**

When I request the layer for example via the OpenLayers preview, it throws an error reporting:

```
Could not convert the value EPSG:32632 into the expected type interface
org.opengis.referencing.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem for parameter targetCRS
```

Oddly enough, when I use the "WPS request builder" (in the GeoServer Web Application) to call `GeorectifyCoverage` with the same parameters, it gives the right output.
So the error must originate somewhere from my SLD document below.

**Can anybody give me a clue what might be wrong with it?**

---

### **Additional Info**

SLD document calling WPS rendering transformation `GeorectifyCoverage`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <NamedLayer>
        <Name>GeorectifyCoverage</Name>
        <UserStyle>
            <Title>Georectify Coverage</Title>
            <Abstract>Warps image to specified GCP</Abstract>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Transformation>
                    <ogc:Function name="gs:GeorectifyCoverage">
                        <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                            <ogc:Literal>data</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:Function>
                        <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                            <ogc:Literal>gcp</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>[[[0, 0], [308639.500, 5154180.500]], [[0, 450], [308639.500, 5150929.500]], [[600, 0], [315730.500, 5154180.500]], [[600, 450], [315730.500, 5150929.500]]]</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:Function>
                        <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                            <ogc:Literal>targetCRS</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>EPSG:32632</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:Function>   
                    </ogc:Function>
                </Transformation>
                <Rule>
                    <RasterSymbolizer>
                        <Opacity>1.0</Opacity>
                    </RasterSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

where `GeorectifyCoverage` requires the following input:

- `data`: input raster (my layer name)
- `gcp`: List of Ground control points (my corner coordinates)
- `targetCRS`: system to use for the output raster (my CRS corresponding to the GCP)

**Notes:**

- When I call a different WPS function like `Contour` using the same document structure and raster image it works perfectly.
- When I change `EPSG:32632` to `EPSG:4326` the same error is reported.
- Changing the raster format (jpeg, TIFF) does not helo.
- Processing the same data offline with the command line tools `gdal_translate` (assign GCPs) and `gdalwarp` results in the desired output.

**My System:**

- Ubuntu 12.04
- OpenGeo Suite 3.0.2
- GeoServer 2.2

Alternative approaches using OpenGeo would also be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same on the GeoServer User mailing list and the GeoSolutions founder Simone Giannecchini himself suggested me the following workaround:

Instead of specifying the input parameter `targetCRS` as a `<ogc:Literal>`, one could pass it to the function via a WMS request. This can be achieved using [Variable substitution in SLD](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/substitution.html), i.e., defining `targetCRS` in the SLD (here called `georectify`) as a `env` request parameter (here `wms_crs`)

```xml
<ogc:Function name="parameter">
    <ogc:Literal>targetCRS</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Function name="env">
            <ogc:Literal>wms_crs</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
</ogc:Function>
```

and then pass down the actual value (`EPSG:32632`) through a WMS request like in

```
.../wms?LAYERS=myworkspace:mylayer&STYLES:georectify&ENV=wms_crs:EPSG:32632&...
```

We tried that out and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually have a working example?
I'm trying to achieve the same result, but I always get the follow exception: "Error rendering coverage on the fast path".. I suspect it's because the GeorectifyCoverage process returns two outputs: result and path.