# Geoserver: gs:Reproject in SLD fails

Tags: geoserver, coordinate-system, sld, wps

I want to reproject data via sld:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
 xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
 xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>RAIN_SLD</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>RAIN</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Transformation>
          <ogc:Function name="gs:BufferFeatureCollection">
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>features</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Function name="gs:Reproject">
                <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                  <ogc:Literal>features</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:Function> <!-- end parameter -->
                <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                  <ogc:Literal>forcedCRS</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>EPSG:4326</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:Function> <!-- end parameter -->
                <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                  <ogc:Literal>targetCRS</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>EPSG:900913</ogc:Literal> <!-- end parameter -->
                </ogc:Function> <!-- end targetCRS -->
              </ogc:Function> <!-- end reporject -->
            </ogc:Function> <!-- end parameter -->
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>distance</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Function name="env">
                <ogc:Literal>BUFFER_DIS</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>10000</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:Function>
            </ogc:Function> <!-- end parameter -->
          </ogc:Function>
        </Transformation>

        <Rule>
          <Name>BUFFER</Name>
          <Title>BUFFER</Title>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>SN</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>A0001</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>

          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#d3d3d3</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>

          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
                <Fill>
                  <CssParameter name="fill">#ff0000</CssParameter>
                </Fill>
              </Mark>
              <Size>6</Size>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

When i requested the layer with the SLD above, i got an error:

> Could not convert the value EPSG:4326 into the expected type interface
>   org.opengis.referencing.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem for parameter
>   forcedCRS.

I found an example:
[Geoserver: Georectification via SLD fails](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65162/geoserver-georectification-via-sld-fails)

It is useful. But in my situation, 2 CRSs(forcedCRS and targetCRS) must be set.

How could I do with it?

Answer (score 1):

The forcedCRS is associated in the layer configuration, so i just specified the targetCRS.

[How to use "gs:Reproject" in sld ?](http://sourceforge.net/p/geoserver/mailman/message/32470775/)
And I checked the "WPS request builder" demo in GeoServer, the parameter "forcedCRS" was override if specified.